# Can somebody help me identify the grammatical rule at play in the sentence, "It was mandatory the each person wipe off equipment..."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I've been asked by a friend taking a TOEIC exam to get an explanation of why "wipe" should be used in the following sentence, as opposed to "wipes":

> It was mandatory that each person wipe[s] off equipment after use with provided spray and wiping towel.

Is it because there is an implied (should) before "wipe"?

Or is it related to the fact that it is "each person" - meaning, of course, multiple people and perhaps substitutable with "they" - i.e. you couldn't say "It was mandatory that they wipe**s**"?

Or is it something completely different?

This one has got me extremely curious, really looking forward to some of your insightful responses.

Comment: *Each person* is always singular, but hearing an implied 'should' helps hear the subjunctive.

Comment: This is the mandative subjunctive, and while it's still widespread in American English, many British English speakers never use it. I'm surprised it's on the TOEIC, which is supposed to be an international test.

Comment: They are three different forms of the mandative construction, all of which are possible with the adjective "mandatory". The mandative subjunctive uses the plain form of the verb, "wipe", In the version with "should" the modal verb "should" is followed by the plain form "wipe". The 3rd kind (called the covert mandative) uses the present tense "wipes".

Comment: @BillJ Wouldn't that be 'wiped' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to accuracy in copying:

> "It was mandatory **the** each person wipe off equipment..."

should be "It was mandatory **that** each person wipe off equipment..."

**wipe** is the present subjunctive.

Some use of the subjunctive is still made in the case of mandatory statements, e.g.

I order/command/require he **be** taken to prison.